# Having trouble with regex in Java 11

Tags: java, regex, java-11, string-matching

Trying to strip server name from: //some.server.name/path/to/a/dir (finishing with /path/to/a/dir)

I have tried 3 different regexes (hardcoded works), but the other two look like they should work but are not. Can anyone point me to why ?

cat test.java

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
public class test
{
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
{

        String rootPath="//server.myco.com/some/path/to/a/doc/root";
        rootPath = rootPath.replace("//[\\w.]*","");
        System.out.println("rootPath - "+rootPath);
        rootPath = rootPath.replace("//[^/]*","");
        System.out.println("rootPath - "+rootPath);
        rootPath = rootPath.replace("//server.myco.com","");
        System.out.println("rootPath - "+rootPath);

}
}
```

Output:

```
rootPath - //server.myco.com/some/path/to/a/doc/root
rootPath - //server.myco.com/some/path/to/a/doc/root
rootPath - /some/path/to/a/doc/root
```

Java 11.0.6:

```
$ java --version
openjdk 11.0.6 2020-01-14
OpenJDK Runtime Environment AdoptOpenJDK (build 11.0.6+10)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM AdoptOpenJDK (build 11.0.6+10, mixed mode)
```

Comment: Were you looking for `.replaceAll` or `.replaceFirst` instead of `.replace` ?

Comment: Thanks,  replaceAll did it.  Why did I need replaceAll ?  There is a single instance in the string.

Comment: Using `.replace` does not take a regex. If you want to replace a single occurrence, then use `.replaceFirst`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use this from the String class:

```
public String replaceAll(String regex, String replacement)
```

instead of this:

```
public String replace(CharSequence target, CharSequence replacement)
```

When you are calling `replace("//[\\w.]*","")` or `replace("//[^/]*","")`, it's searching `"//[\\w.]*"` or `"//[^/]*"` respectively, and trying to replace with the empty string. As there is no such string in the given string, no change is there.

But `replaceAll("//[\\w.]*","")` takes regex as the first argument. Hence it will work.

Oracle Java 11 reference for String [replace()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#replace(java.lang.CharSequence,java.lang.CharSequence)) and [replaceAll()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String,java.lang.String))

Answer (score 3):

Please refrain from using a regular expression to parse a URI. Most languages these days include libraries to parse a URI/URL into a various parts.

Here is a proper example:

```java
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;

public class ExtractPath {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String rootPath = "//server.myco.com/some/path/to/a/doc/root";
        String path = extractPath(rootPath);
        System.out.println(path.equals("/some/path/to/a/doc/root")); // true
    }

    public static String extractPath(String location) {
        try {
            return new URI(location).getPath();
        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do not use URL for checking/parsing, use URI instead:  "As mentioned, URL and URLConnection rely on protocol handlers which must be present, otherwise an Exception is thrown."

Comment: Its not a URL per se,  but I see your point.  Thanks.

Comment: @UsagiMiyamoto I addressed this. Thanks.

Comment: When you’re going to wrap the `URISyntaxException` in an unchecked exception anyway, you can use `return URI.create(location).getPath();` in the first place. Then, you’ll get an `IllegalArgumentException` wrapping the `URISyntaxException` if one occurred, without the need to do it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

You can utilize the *[URI](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/net/URI.html)* class for this.

```java
URI u = new URI("//server.myco.com/some/path/to/a/doc/root");
String p = u.getPath();
```

Output

```
/some/path/to/a/doc/root
```